# How to UNNEST and write ALL repeated rows into single line

Tags: google-bigquery

Currently, I have a nested table with product name and ingredients. But need to UNNEST() it and write all ingredients in a single line.

```
SELECT productTitle, ingridientTitle  FROM `TABLE`, UNNEST(ingredients)
```

From this :

```
productTitle             ingridientTitle
     A                         A
                               C
                               D
                               E

     B
                               A
                               B

     C
                               A
                               C
```

To This:

```
productTitle             ingridientTitle
     A                        A,C,D,E
     B                        A,B
     c                        A,C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to unnest, you can use `ARRAY_TO_STRING()`:

```
with a as (
select 'A' as productTitle
, ['A', 'B' , 'C' , 'D', 'E'] as ingridientTitle 
union all 
select 'B' as productTitle
, ['A', 'B'] as ingridientTitle 
union all 
select 'C' as productTitle
, ['A',  'E'] as ingridientTitle 
)
select productTitle , ARRAY_TO_STRING(ingridientTitle, ",")
from a
```